# Fated to earn money (simple algebra used but may require other things)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, puzzle

I posted this on puzzling stack exchange before I flagged it to delete it because I think it may be a pure mathematics question (it might take awhile before it's closed on puzzling stack exchange though). I also think the people here may be more inclined to answer this question.

https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87949/fated-to-earn-money

Here is my problem:

Joe has investments in Company A, Company B, and Company C.

Joe is fated to earn $25.00 from Company A within 2 days from now.

Joe is fated to earn $45.00 from Company B within 3 days from now.

Joe is fated to earn $100.00 from Company C within 5 days from now.

Joe is fated to earn no more than $26.00 from Company C and Company B on day 1 (1 day from now).

Joe is fated to earn at least $14.00 from Company A and Company C on day 2 (2 days from now).

Joe has to earn twice the amount of money on the first day than the second day from Companies A, B, and C and twice the amount of money on the second day than the third day from Companies A, B, and C. This can be expressed algebraically as Joe earning x money on day 3 (3 days from now), 2x money on day 2 (2 days from now), and 4x money on day 1 (1 day from now).

Joe can earn whatever amount of money (that satisfies the other conditions) from Companies A, B, and C on day 4 and day 5 (4 and 5 days from now).

What is the lowest amount of money Joe can earn on day 1 (1 day from now) from Companies A, B, and C? Explain your reasoning.

P.S. How come there doesn't seem to be good formulas to use for this question?

Edit: I do know the answer to this question, but I have no idea why. If you can explain your reasoning, that would be great!

Hint:

> You won't have to calculate in cents for this question.

Comment: Any comments? What's with the downvote? Is it a valid mathematics question or not completely mathematics?

Comment: Don't worry, I upvoted this since it's a pretty good puzzle